# Strange where clause behavior with upper(string) in ('str1','str2','str3')

Tags: sql, string, hive, where-clause, uppercase

When I run the code

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE
date BETWEEN '20200520' and '20200520' 
and country_id in ('US','us','USA')

--and upper(country_id) in ('US''JP','IN','GB','CA')
and app_id in (1180,1233)
LIMIT 5
```

I get the result like below
[image]

However, if I add the where clause below, no data are returned.

```
SELECT * FROM
    tbl
WHERE
date BETWEEN '20200520' and '20200520' 
and country_id in ('US','us','USA')
and upper(country_id) in ('US''JP','IN','GB','CA')
and app_id in (1180,1233)
LIMIT 5
```

Shouldn't the records with country_id in ('US' and 'us') still be returned? What's wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=77f7761b0024c60fc7e0a469521deb51)

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a comma.

and upper(country_id) in (**'US''JP'**,'IN','GB','CA')

Answer (score 1):

use or instead of and

```
SELECT * FROM
    tbl
WHERE
date BETWEEN '20200520' and '20200520' 
and (country_id in ('US','us','USA')
or upper(country_id) in ('US','JP','IN','GB','CA')
)
and app_id in (1180,1233)
LIMIT 5
```